# GitPython get remote git url from sub-url

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am using GitPython to work with a remote repository.
The user is providing a URL that is a file inside the repository, something like this

```
https://github.com/Namespace/Project/tree/master/my-folder
```

Is it possible to initialize a `Repo` from that url using something similar to this command valid for local repos? `git.Repo("local_repo_path/my-folder", search_parent_directories=True)`

At the moment I am looking for `/tree` in the url and manually cutting away the last part, using it later to recover the specific path/file, but I am wondering if there is a simpler/better way using native functions from the library.

Answer (score 0):

I think you won't find an answer because it would be host dependent. You assume the host is `github`, but for others, it could be `gitlab` or `azure` or `bitbucket` and many others. Each one of those hosts have different file structure, hence different URLs.

You will need to continue *manually* doing string manipulation to get through and keep in mind your solution is github specific. There is no `tree` in other hosts urls.